# Re-Routing my sump discharge piping inside the house

Tags: sump-pump

I am thinking about changing the route my sump pump discharge pipetakes to get to the exterior wall.  What are some things to consider for the inside route from pump to exterior wall?

I know distance is one. How can I determine what my pump can handle?

Do more 90 degree turns in the route increase load on pump?

How much vertical can I do? How can I determine what my pump can handle?

Right now, the discharges comes up about 8 feet from pump, takes a 90 and runs straight to the exterior wall about 25 feet.

My future plan is to have it come up 8 feet, make a few lefts and rights to get around A/C unit, and then travel about 25 feet to a new exterior wall.

I have a “ProFlo PF92341 - 3/10 HP Cast Iron Submersible Sump Pump w/ Vertical Float Switch”

Any advice would be great. Any other considerations?

Answer (score 1):

Adding in more bends and more horizontal run *will* increase the load on the pump.  However this is a sump pump, so the volume being pumped is quite low and hence the water speeds are low (which means the load from a bend is low too).

This pump has a [maximum head](http://image.proflo.com/prodimages/Proflo/specs/PF92341spec.pdf) of 25 feet, so it has plenty of spare pressure to deal with some bends.

Comment: I have been reading and i have seen that i should try to use 2 45s instead of a 90.  if  I only have 2-3 90s, 25 feet of horizontal, and 8/9 feet vertical, am i ok?    Am i overthinking this?

Answer (score 1):

> Do more 90 degree turns in the route increase load on pump?

Yes

> How can I determine what my pump can handle?

It's on the label.

The more bends you place into the discharge the slower the flow and harder the pump has to work, you can kill the pump with too many bends and to much head pressure so adding in more bends than necessary is not advisable. Sweeping elbows instead of 90 degree bends are recommend a well, water doesn't like flowing though a giant mess of elbows and the straightest path to the outlet is the desired method.

Comment: The maximum head is on the label.  How much head is equivalent to a 90⁰ bend, a nice swept curve, or a metre/yard of run will not be on the label - and that is what the OP is asking.

Comment: https://www.pipeflow.com/pipe-pressure-drop-calculations

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.metropumps.com/ResourcesFrictionLossData.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwii3ILasIfiAhUPhOAKHetiBZcQFjAMegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw35SnwOtYT6OMjIEK1eT4hz&cshid=1557162069446

Comment: so my pump can handle  a max head of 25 feet.    Looking at that chart If i look at 90deg turn on 1 1/2 pipe, i get 0.63.    thats where I end.  I know enough to know bends cause flow disruptions....I have done some reading, and what i can gather is with 9 feet of rise, 3 elbows, and 25 feet of horizontal distance, i should be good.

Comment: Just don't restrict the pump beyond is limitations and reduce the number of bends to an absolute minimum. Using sweeps instead of 90's and using the largest diameter pipe available is the best option. If you're rerouting for aesthetics instead of functionalities then you're begging for trouble and you should scrap that plan ASAP. Pretty and nice visually appealing basements full of damp and waterlogged crap are secondary to dry basements.

Comment: I disagree.  Obviously "don't restrict the pump beyond its limitations", but there's no reason not to add in some bends and extra run provided you don't go beyond the pump's limitations.